# Complément, virgule puis ordre normal ou complement et inversion de sujet et verbe ?

Tags: grammaire, inversion

Y a-t-il quelque différence entre les deux formes suivantes ?

> Au commencement, Dieu créa les cieux et la terre.

et

> Au commencement créa Dieu les cieux et la terre.

En général, quand le complément est posé au début de la phrase, peut-on choisir entre faire l'inversion ou mettre une virgule et après utiliser l'ordre normal (sujet, verbe, puis objet) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'inversion ne se fait pas lorsque le verbe est transitif ; donc elle n'est pas possible dans la seconde phrase.

L'inversion se fait lorsque le verbe est intransitif ; quelques exemples suivent.

- Dans la panière dormaient deux chiots au poil noir luisant.
- Finalement arriva la pire des catastrophes.
- Dans le froid de l'hiver se trouve le repos de la nature.
- Sur la campagne endormie tombe la neige silencieuse.

Il y a certaines difficultés avec des verbe comme « manger » qui ont deux emplois.

- <s>Sur des tables sales mangeaient des hommes des légumes.</s>
- Sur des tables sales mangeaient des hommes trapus.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. L'exemple que j'ai choisi n'est pas très bon ... Mais enfin, est-ce qu'il a de différence entre "Finalement arriva la pire des catastrophes" et "Finalement, la pire des catastrophes arriva" ?

Comment: Dites « est-ce qu'il y a **une** différence entre etc. ». Non, il n'y a pas de différence de sens! (remarquez que le « de » s'utilise avec la négation.) La différence est purement dans le style : dans le langage courant et la langue parlée il ne faut  pas faire cette inversion ; elle devient possible dans la langue littéraire, et  on la trouve très souvent en poésie.

Comment: Oui, j'ai imaginé que cela serait le cas ... Je sais qu'informellement les français diraient plutôt « la pire des catastrophes est finalement arrivée » (en suivant la structure SVO), mais je ne savais pas si une fois que l'on mettais le complément au début, la forme avec la virgule aurait le même sens et valeur stylistique que la forme avec l'inversion. Merci beaucoup pour la réponse et les commentaires.

Comment: « La pire des catastrophes est finalement arrivée. » convient dans la langue écrite et dans la langue parlée ; il faudrait cependant que je modifie légèrement ce que j'affirme dans mon commentaire précédent ; l'inversion dans la langue parlée n'est pas courante mais peut être utilisée dans certains cas, en particulier par des personnes avec une bonne maitrise de la langue.